# Groupbox with Panel

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a groupbox, inside which I have added a panel. The Panel contains 3 labels. The intended functionality is that as the text on the label increases, the Panel shows the Scrollbar.
However, its not happening. I have tried a lot, with panel inside and outside the groupbox. Setting the MaxSize of labels and setting off the AutoSize but all in vain.
P.s. The AutoScroll property is set to true.

Please suggest any wayout.

Comment: Have you set AutoScroll-Property to true?

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is set the panel's `AutoScroll` property to `true`.

```
myPanel.AutoScroll = true;
```

I hope this helps.

---

Extension: You seem sceptical. Here is an image of the form with just want you want. All I did was do the above.

[image: As Above]

Comment: myPanel.AutoSize=false; label.AutoSize=true;myPanel.AutoScroll=true;

Comment: Any way out would be helpful.

Comment: You can see the dialog above. I have not done anything but create a new form, add group box, add panel and set to dock fill. Add lables and set the setting I have stated above...